# R: Non-standard evaluation of dynamic variables within pipes. Replacing (") with (`)

Tags: r, non-standard-evaluation

I am attempting to use a dynamic string in a `dplyr` `pipe` and a `lapply` function. Where the string is used to name a column which is later used within a `filter`. The issue occurs where attempting filter to remove any rows with a resultant NA (using `!is.na()`) within the `filter`.

Typically one would use Non-standard evaluation such as `filter_` for such a situation, however due to the called string being within `is.na()`, the `filter_` has no effect. I require the string to be called wrapped using the prime symbol (`) as opposed to quotation marks (").

Below is a minimal example minus the `lapply` function.

```
df <- data.frame("one"=c(1,2,3,4),"two"=c(4,NA,2,1))
storeddate <- "Jan17-01-92"
finaldf <- df %>%
 mutate(!!storeddate := one+two) %>%
 filter(!is.na(storeddate)) #the storeddate string call requires formatting as `Jan17-01-92` as opposed to "Jan17-01-92".
```

I am aware that I could simply reformat the initial string, however I am more curious of finding a way to calls strings wrapped in a different format for use within other scenarios.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the filter, you need to turn the string into a symbol. For example

```
df %>%
  mutate(!!storeddate := one+two) %>% 
  filter(!is.na(!!as.name(storeddate)))

#   one two Jan17-01-92
# 1   1   4           5
# 2   3   2           5
# 3   4   1           5
```

So it's not about replacing quotes. It the different between strings and symbols/names in R.

Comment: Great, the unquoting as `as.name` does the trick! Thanks for the tip about strings, symbols and names. I wasn't sure on the terminology. (I have upvoted this answer, but too low a reputation!)

Answer (score 1):

Add the `!!` unquoting operator inside the `is.na` call:

```
finaldf <- df %>%
 mutate(!!storeddate := one+two) %>%
 filter(!is.na(!!storeddate))
```

Comment: Did you test this? What version of dplyr are you using? This did not work for me. It did not filter out the row with the NA.